# MySQL database size is larger than export file?

Tags: mysql, database, web-hosting

I have Drupal site with MySQL database on my hosting provider. He tells me that my DB is almost on max limit about 1GB but when I export DB to output file, the file is only 80 MB for whole DB.

It is logical DB to be smaller than my output file or same but almost when DB on hosting is 10 times larger than export file, I think it is impossible.

Can you help me to find out is it possible, or my hosting provider manipulate my data and write me every day messages to get bigger DB storage for more money?

Comment: How did you export the DB hosted in your provider to see how much data are stored? Doesn't your DB grow? Also check http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-calculate-the-mysql-database-size/

Comment: yes, I exported it into a file. *.sql. File is 80 MB

Answer (score 3):

Functioning MySQL databases use plenty of data storage for such things as indexes. A 12x ratio between your raw (exported) data size and the disk space your database uses is a large ratio, but it's still very possible.

MySQL makes the tradeoff of using lots of disk space to improve query performance. That's a wise tradeoff these days because the cost of disk space is low, and decreasing very fast.

You may (or may not) recover some data space by going in to phpmyadmin and optimizing all your tables.  This query will optimize a list of tables.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename, tablename, tablename
```

It's smart to back up your data base before doing this.

A 1GiB limit on a MySQL database size is absurdly low. (A GiB of storage at AWS or another cloud provider costs less than $US 0.20 per month these days.) It may be time to get a better hosting service.